# reference protocol support in Karaf

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf

When I tried to use `reference:file:/path/to.jar` as a bundle URL in Karaf integration tests, I got "Unknown protocol: reference" errors. There are some mentions of `reference:` URLs on Karaf mailing list, but this isn't clear to me:

1. Should they work by default?
2. If not, how do I enable them? Presumably I need a suitable bundle providing URLHandlerService, but which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The URL handlers in Karaf are provided by the [Pax-Url project](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxurl), I don't think the reference one is provided by default (as primarily for test support).
2. You can find pax-url-reference via maven [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.ops4j.pax.url%22%20AND%20a%3a%22pax-url-reference%22)

Comment: @Alexey you accepted this answer so I assume you got this to work. I added `mavenBundle("org.ops4j.pax.url", "pax-url-reference", "1.6.0")` to my container configuration and then also `pax-url-commons` `1.6.0` and `pax-url-commons` `1.6.0` to resolve the missing requirements, but still get the error `java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: reference:`. Any hints? I'm running on Pax Exam 3.2 and Karaf 2.3.2 btw.

Comment: @benjamin - has the pax-url-reference bundle been started before your reference bundle?  If not try something like: `mavenBundle("org.ops4j.pax.url", "pax-url-reference", "1.6.0").startLevel(1);  bundle("reference:...").startLevel(2);`

Comment: @benjamin add **-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.ops4j.pax.url** to the jvm args

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated. Unfortunately I had no luck with your suggestions. I already had the JVM property, and the bundle start level configuration does also not work. May it has to to with the fact that the test is deployed as a feature, since I'm using `useDeployFolder(false)`? (Turning that to true has it's own set of problems). Because from the error message, Karaf won't install the complete exam feature: `org.apache.karaf.features.core - 2.3.2 | Error when installing feature exam: java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: reference`.

Comment: [This mailing list post](http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/How-can-I-enable-reference-URL-handler-td3988050.html) seems to backup my conjecture. I'll try to find a way to add those bundles to the system startup, and then in may work.